# Error when installing apache beam in datalab instance in GCP using python2 kernel

Tags: python-2.7, pip, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to install apache beam in the datalab instance on GCP, but running into the following issue, would really love a way to fix this, I am not that proficient with either pip or datalab at the moment, errors are at the bottom:

```
        Collecting apache-beam[gcp]
Requirement already satisfied: dill<=0.2.8.2,>=0.2.6 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (0.2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pydot<1.3,>=1.2.0 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (1.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: oauth2client<5,>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mock<3.0.0,>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (2.0.0)
Collecting typing<3.7.0,>=3.6.0 (from apache-beam[gcp])
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/4d/4e5985d075d241d686a1663fa1f88b61d544658d08c1375c7c6aac32afc3/typing-3.6.4-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml<4.0.0,>=3.12 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (3.12)
Collecting pyvcf<0.7.0,>=0.6.8 (from apache-beam[gcp])
Requirement already satisfied: future<1.0.0,>=0.16.0 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: avro<2.0.0,>=1.8.1 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (1.8.2)
Collecting fastavro==0.19.7 (from apache-beam[gcp])
Requirement already satisfied: crcmod<2.0,>=1.7 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: httplib2<=0.11.3,>=0.8 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (0.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: futures<4.0.0,>=3.1.1 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio<2,>=1.8 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six<1.12,>=1.9 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf<4,>=3.5.0.post1 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (3.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: hdfs<3.0.0,>=2.1.0 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (2.1.0)
Collecting pytz<=2018.4,>=2018.3 (from apache-beam[gcp])
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/83/15f7833b70d3e067ca91467ca245bae0f6fe56ddc7451aa0dc5606b120f2/pytz-2018.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-apitools<=0.5.20,>=0.5.18; extra == "gcp" (from apache-beam[gcp])
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/0c/64f84f91643f775fdb64c6c10f4a4f0d827f8b0d98a2ba2b4bb9dc2f8646/google_apitools-0.5.20-py2-none-any.whl (330kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 337kB 5.1MB/s ta 0:00:01
Collecting proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1==0.15.4; extra == "gcp" (from apache-beam[gcp])
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/a2/2eeffa0069830f00016196dfdd69491cf562372b5353f2e8e378b3c2cb0a/proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1-0.15.4.tar.gz
Collecting google-cloud-bigquery==0.25.0; extra == "gcp" (from apache-beam[gcp])
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/67/6165c516ff6ceaa62eb61f11d8451e1b0acc4d3775e181630aba9652babb/google_cloud_bigquery-0.25.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 10.1MB/s ta 0:00:01
Collecting google-cloud-pubsub==0.26.0; extra == "gcp" (from apache-beam[gcp])
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/92/c74a643126d58505daec9addf872dfaffea3305981b90cc435f4b9213cdd/google_cloud_pubsub-0.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: googledatastore==7.0.1; extra == "gcp" in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (7.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1<=0.90.4,>=0.90.0; extra == "gcp" in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam[gcp]) (0.90.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.1.4 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pydot<1.3,>=1.2.0->apache-beam[gcp]) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from oauth2client<5,>=2.0.1->apache-beam[gcp]) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from oauth2client<5,>=2.0.1->apache-beam[gcp]) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa>=3.1.4 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from oauth2client<5,>=2.0.1->apache-beam[gcp]) (3.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: funcsigs>=1 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from mock<3.0.0,>=1.0.1->apache-beam[gcp]) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr>=0.11 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from mock<3.0.0,>=1.0.1->apache-beam[gcp]) (4.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyvcf<0.7.0,>=0.6.8->apache-beam[gcp]) (39.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34>=1.0.4 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from grpcio<2,>=1.8->apache-beam[gcp]) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.7.0 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from hdfs<3.0.0,>=2.1.0->apache-beam[gcp]) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: docopt in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from hdfs<3.0.0,>=2.1.0->apache-beam[gcp]) (0.6.2)
Collecting fasteners>=0.14 (from google-apitools<=0.5.20,>=0.5.18; extra == "gcp"->apache-beam[gcp])
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/3a/096c7ad18e102d4f219f5dd15951f9728ca5092a3385d2e8f79a7c1e1017/fasteners-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1==0.15.4; extra == "gcp"->apache-beam[gcp]) (1.5.3)
Collecting google-cloud-core<0.26dev,>=0.25.0 (from google-cloud-bigquery==0.25.0; extra == "gcp"->apache-beam[gcp])
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/dd/00e90bd1f6788f06ca5ea83a0ec8dd76350b38303bb8f09d2bf692eb1294/google_cloud_core-0.25.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (52kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 8.0MB/s ta 0:00:011
Collecting gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1<0.16dev,>=0.15.0 (from google-cloud-pubsub==0.26.0; extra == "gcp"->apache-beam[gcp])
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a7/0225bd7a95e037a0afa90b2dd9534d0c79cd62283a5bddb30a3197579cbc/gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1-0.15.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: ordereddict in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from funcsigs>=1->mock<3.0.0,>=1.0.1->apache-beam[gcp]) (1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.7.0->hdfs<3.0.0,>=2.1.0->apache-beam[gcp]) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.7.0->hdfs<3.0.0,>=2.1.0->apache-beam[gcp]) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.7.0->hdfs<3.0.0,>=2.1.0->apache-beam[gcp]) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.7.0->hdfs<3.0.0,>=2.1.0->apache-beam[gcp]) (2018.4.16)
Collecting monotonic>=0.1 (from fasteners>=0.14->google-apitools<=0.5.20,>=0.5.18; extra == "gcp"->apache-beam[gcp])
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/aa/063eca6a416f397bd99552c534c6d11d57f58f2e94c14780f3bbf818c4cf/monotonic-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-httplib2 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from google-cloud-core<0.26dev,>=0.25.0->google-cloud-bigquery==0.25.0; extra == "gcp"->apache-beam[gcp]) (0.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<2.0.0dev,>=0.4.0 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from google-cloud-core<0.26dev,>=0.25.0->google-cloud-bigquery==0.25.0; extra == "gcp"->apache-beam[gcp]) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-gax<0.16dev,>=0.15.7 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1<0.16dev,>=0.15.0->google-cloud-pubsub==0.26.0; extra == "gcp"->apache-beam[gcp]) (0.15.16)
Requirement already satisfied: grpc-google-iam-v1<0.12dev,>=0.11.1 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1<0.16dev,>=0.15.0->google-cloud-pubsub==0.26.0; extra == "gcp"->apache-beam[gcp]) (0.11.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from google-auth<2.0.0dev,>=0.4.0->google-cloud-core<0.26dev,>=0.25.0->google-cloud-bigquery==0.25.0; extra == "gcp"->apache-beam[gcp]) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ply==3.8 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from google-gax<0.16dev,>=0.15.7->gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1<0.16dev,>=0.15.0->google-cloud-pubsub==0.26.0; extra == "gcp"->apache-beam[gcp]) (3.8)
Building wheels for collected packages: proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1, gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 ... - done
  Stored in directory: /content/.cache/pip/wheels/d1/0d/9e/95e7192ab2625847ac40b2bc618800bf5b6c984cd572a83314
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 ... - done
  Stored in directory: /content/.cache/pip/wheels/f4/2b/10/bdcbc9be2ae4e437232e118056f026025cf2cc46d6dcf0d69d
Successfully built proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1
google-cloud-storage 1.6.0 has requirement google-cloud-core<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-firestore 0.28.0 has requirement google-cloud-core<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-bigtable 0.28.1 has requirement google-cloud-core<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-dataflow 2.0.0 has requirement google-apitools==0.5.10, but you'll have google-apitools 0.5.20 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-dataflow 2.0.0 has requirement google-cloud-bigquery<0.24.0,>=0.23.0, but you'll have google-cloud-bigquery 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-dataflow 2.0.0 has requirement httplib2<0.10,>=0.8, but you'll have httplib2 0.11.3 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-dataflow 2.0.0 has requirement proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1==0.90.0, but you'll have proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1 0.90.4 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-dataflow 2.0.0 has requirement protobuf==3.2.0, but you'll have protobuf 3.5.2 which is incompatible.
pandas-gbq 0.3.0 has requirement google-cloud-bigquery>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-bigquery 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-monitoring 0.28.1 has requirement google-cloud-core<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-error-reporting 0.28.0 has requirement google-cloud-core<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-translate 1.3.1 has requirement google-cloud-core<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-spanner 0.29.0 has requirement google-cloud-core[grpc]<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-resource-manager 0.28.1 has requirement google-cloud-core<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-speech 0.30.0 has requirement google-cloud-core[grpc]<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-runtimeconfig 0.28.1 has requirement google-cloud-core<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud 0.33.1 has requirement google-cloud-bigquery<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-bigquery 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud 0.33.1 has requirement google-cloud-core<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud 0.33.1 has requirement google-cloud-pubsub<0.31dev,>=0.30.0, but you'll have google-cloud-pubsub 0.26.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-trace 0.17.0 has requirement google-cloud-core[grpc]<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-logging 1.4.0 has requirement google-cloud-core[grpc]<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-dns 0.28.0 has requirement google-cloud-core<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-datastore 1.4.0 has requirement google-cloud-core<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: typing, pyvcf, fastavro, pytz, monotonic, fasteners, google-apitools, proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1, google-cloud-core, google-cloud-bigquery, gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam
  Found existing installation: pytz 2016.7
Cannot uninstall 'pytz'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I selected python2 kernel for this brand new notebook. virtualenv is also on version 16. and pip is on version 18. the VM was provisioned using the datalab command via cloud shell
any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Datalab by default now uses Python 3 and your pip install is happening in Python 3 even though the kernel is Python 2 because %%bash opens up a new shell in which the conda activate of Python 2 has not happened.

To fix, this, change your pip install of apache-beam[gcp] as follows:

```
%%bash
source activate py2env
conda install -y pytz
pip uninstall -y google-cloud-dataflow
pip install --upgrade apache-beam[gcp]
```

Comment: Hi, it seems not enough on my side.

pandas-gbq 0.3.0 has requirement google-cloud-bigquery>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-bigquery 0.25.0 which is incompatible.

google-cloud-monitoring 0.28.0 has requirement google-cloud-core<0.29dev,>=0.28.0, but you'll have google-cloud-core 0.25.0 which is incompatible.

Cannot uninstall 'pytz'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Still issues with versions :(